# Recursive directory creation fails on device

Tags: java, io, codenameone, mkdirs

My code runs in the simulator, but crashes on Android with a `FileNotFoundException` as it tries to `FileSystemStorage#openOutputStream` in an non-existing directory. I create all the needed directories recursively before using

```
private void ensureParentDirs(String file) {
    final int j = file.lastIndexOf("/");
    final String s = file.substring(0, j);
    if (storage.isDirectory(s)) return;
    storage.mkdir(s);
    if (storage.isDirectory(s)) return;
    ensureParentDirs(s);
    storage.mkdir(s);
    if (storage.isDirectory(s)) return;
    Log.p("Cannot create directory: " + s);
}
```

which is supposed to work like `new File(file).getParentFile().mkdirs()`. It might be wrong, but then it shouldn't run in the simulator either, so I'd call it a bug.

I get the message

```
Cannot create directory:
file:///data/user/0/my.package.name/files//dump/000/abcd
```

but the parent directory ("000") has been successfully created. Using `adb shell`, I can create the directory using

```
mkdir /data/data/my.package.name/files/dump/000/abcd
```

so I can't see what's wrong. Any idea?

Comment: Why are you invoking `mkdir()` and not `mkdirs()`? Notice the method returns a boolean if the operation was successful. What did it return?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog There's no `mkdirs` in your `com.codename1.io.FileSystemStorage` and `mkdir` is `void`. I guess, you mean `File`, but that's not what I'm using. I guess, I should, but that's the third thing (I started with `Storage`). `+++` I see, I can use `FSS` with `File` easily.... however, what I'm doing doesn't look much different from `mkdirs`.

Comment: Does it work when you don't have the double slash (`... files//dump ...`)?

Comment: @Henry I didn't try... I know I should, but I've already spent too much time on this. I was thinking about it, but `....files//dump` could be created, so double slashes in general should work. And in the meantime, I rewrote the code (for unrelated reasons....).

Comment: @ShaiAlmog It looks like there was a problem with doubles slashes as Henry assumed.

Comment: @Henry After my rewrite, the double slashes are gone and so is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was (possibly still existent) problem with double slashes. My path was

```
/dump/000/abcd
```

and I transformed it via

```
path -> APP_HOME_PATH + "/" + path
```

into

```
file:///data/user/0/my.package.name/files//dump/000/abcd
```

which failed because of the double slashes, while

```
dump/000/abcd
```

transforms into

```
file:///data/user/0/my.package.name/files/dump/000/abcd
```

and works correctly.